# Show all articles from past years to till date

Tags: php, wordpress

I am facing problem of showing articles from past years till current year in wordpress.

The problem is that i have articles in two years (2014, 2015). By query `wp_query` i can display all articles from 2015 and 2014 also. But in 2014 its displaying articles from june onwards means current month and march april may are missing.

This is my link http://www.za-beauty.in/lets-talk-za/

You can check it in 2014 year March April May articles don't come on left side.

My code below

```
   <?php 
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'articles',


'tax_query' => array(
array(
'taxonomy' => 'article_categories',
'field'    => 'term_id',
'terms'    => array( 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24 ),

),
),
);
//print_r($args);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
```

Please help .

I want to display all articles of mine and if i add new articles in 2016 years in future it should not create problems the articles should display all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have solved this problem on my own. The problem is that we have to explicitly define date query parameter so that it shows the post from a given range. Without date query it will show the post from the current month, to override this we have to tell the query to show post from this range to that range (JAN 2014 to DEC 2015).

HERE IS THE REVISED CODE :)

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'articles',
'posts_per_page' => -1,    // important to display all post

    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after' => 'January 1st, 2014',
            'before' => 'December 31st, 2016',
        ),
     ),

'tax_query' => array(
array(
'taxonomy' => 'article_categories',
'field'    => 'term_id',
'terms'    => array( 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24 ),

),
),
);

//print_r($args);           
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 2):

Most probably your problem lies in `posts_per_page`. If you don't specify the `posts_per_page` parameter, your query will use the blog's default `posts_per_page` setting as set in the reading setting page. If this is set to say 20, your custom query will only get 20 posts per page. In most propability, this is what you are seeing

You should set `posts_per_page` explicitely in your query to get more posts. A value of `-1` will get all posts matching your query.

Just one note, reset your custom query and all custom queries with `wp_reset_postdata()` after you are done

Comment: Its not working now also ... i think its something with date query please come one help me ....

Comment: I see no date query anywhere

Comment: thats why i have posted here so that some one can find fault in my query and suggest me .

By the way i have solved it on my own . Thanks for your help buddy :)